# How do I get how many computers I have delivered per date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following columns:

**Inventory**

```
ID,
SerialComputer,
RegistrationDate,
Deadline
```

I want to make a query in which the first column shows me all the dates on which computers have been delivered, and next to the amount of computers that were delivered on that date, how can I make that possible in SQL Server?

I know I get the dates this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Deadline 
FROM Inventory 
ORDER BY Deadline
```

How do I add the `COUNT ()` with the `SerialComputer` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do aggregation using `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT Deadline, COUNT(*) AS [# computers delivered]
FROM Inventory 
GROUP BY Deadline;
```

`DISTINCT` will remove duplicate values so, that will not help you.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, `deadline` is the delivery date.  If so, you want aggregation:

```
SELECT Deadline, COUNT(*)
FROM Inventory 
GROUP BY Deadline
ORDER BY Deadline
```